# run php script after wget download is complete

Tags: php, upload, download, wget

I need to get notification on some script that file has been successfully downloaded with WGET, so I'll need to upload it to another server. Can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
wget "http://example.com/path_to_file.tar.gz" && php scriptname.php file.tar.gz
```

Comment: this cant work in the background.. so if I'm using php to run the shell command(wget http://path/to/file.tar.gz && php scriptname.php file.tar.gz) php will wait until file is downloaded.. thats why I need to run wget in background, but if so than script is running at the same time, that isnt correct for me :(

Comment: sure it can. surround the whole `wget && php` with brackets: `(wget && php)`, which invokes a subshell, and you can send that into the background: `(wget && php) &`

Answer (score 1):

Why not perform the download with `cUrl` in php instead, then the PHP script can be run in the background and continue when the download is complete?